# Opening JQUERY UI dialog via Ajax with loading icon

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

My jquery UI script works good. My `#dialog` has a couple of PHP sql Queries which fetches results. In this case after clicking the `#open` i want to use Ajax reguest. For example: I click the `#open`, after clicking UI dialog opens and inside dialog loads `user_settings.php`, while loading, it shows: Please wait, loading....

After a few seconds, it loads `user_settings.php`. I think the way which i have used, can load my `index.php` heavy.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#dialog").load('ajax_dialog/user_settings.php')
    .dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false, 
        show: 'fade', 
        position: 'center center', 
        resizable:false, 
        draggable:false, 
        modal:true
    });

    $("#open").click(
        function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog('open');
            return false;
        }
    );

});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<a id ="open" href="#">Open jquery UI DIALOG</a>
    <div id="dialog" Title="My Jquery UI dialog"></div>
```

Comment: personally, i can't figure out what you are asking. maybe you should rephrase your problem as a question.

Comment: What exactly is ununderstandable for you?

Comment: "I think the way which i have used, can load my index.php heavy." - is a confusing statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alex told you, is a bit confusing your question, but I think I understood what you want to do (I hope!).

**HTML**

```
<a id ="open" href="#">Open jquery UI DIALOG</a>
<div id="dialog" Title="My Jquery UI dialog">Please wait, loading...</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#open").click(function(){
      $.ajax({
         type:       "POST",
         url:        "ajax_dialog/user_settings.php",
         dataType:   'html',
         success:    function(data){
            $('#dialog').html(data);
         }
      });
   });
});
```

When you click on `open`, your dialog will display a "Please wait, loading..." message. After a few seconds, your dialog content will be replaced with your `user_settings.php` content.

If you don't echo nothing on your `user_settings.php` file, just replace the line `$('#dialog').html(data);` with your desire content.

Happy coding!